# "Undo" databinding change if save button is not clicked

Tags: xaml, data-binding, xamarin.forms

Is that possible?

What I have is just a **list** and **edit** page

- A page with a list of items
- Edit page where items from the first page are edited
- Where the edit page has a cancel and save button

When I press the save button, I save the item and navigate to the previous page where the item is updated. *So databinding between the pages works just fine.*

**What I need is to *"undo" the databinding* changes I did if I click cancel or navigate back.**

**What I have working** but *I feel is maybe **not** the way to go*, is a "oldObject" and a "didClickSaveButton" property that I check on the first page (OnAppearing) when I come back to it and revert to the old values if the save button was not clicked.

Is there not a better way for this? Something inbuilt maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a ViewModel for your edit page.  When the page loads, use the selected domain object to create your VM.  If the user selects save, persist the changes from the VM back to the domain object.  If the user cancels, then do nothing.

Comment: Yes I was thinking that this could be my problem. Would you recommend then always creating a new ViewModel for each xaml page I create? I just can´t find any guideline for that anywhere...

Comment: I think in MVVM this is the ideal approach

Answer (score 1):

Just clone your domain object and pass it to your viewmodel for the databind. I followed a quick and dirty approach

```
public static T Clone<T>(T source)
        {
            var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serialized);
        }
```

and yes create a new viewmodel for each page